# Why does my page keep trying to load when using post

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

So Im using stripe to add a payment option. However once I submit the form post it, the page just keeps trying to load. I was wondering if anyone could tell me why this is. Thanks.

Here is the part of the HTML with the form

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
    <span>Card Number</span>
    <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
    <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
    <span>CVC</span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
</form>
```

Here is the server.js

```
app.post('/payments.html', function(req, res) {
  var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express

  // Create a charge: this will charge the user's card
  var charge = stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 1000, // Amount in cents
    currency: "usd",
    source: token,
    description: "Example charge"
  }, function(err, charge) {
    if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
      // The card has been declined
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You never send a response.

Comment: That will reload the page, I was hoping to not having the page reload

Comment: You have to send a response for it to come back. To not have the page reload you'll need to read up on AJAX and learn how to submit your form that way.